# MFMessageComposeViewController in a UITableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to show an MFMessageComposeViewController from within a custom TableViewCell class but I get an error saying: "Multiple inheritance from classes UITableViewCell and UIViewController." I know that UIViewController is required for MFMessageComposeViewController, so how can I go about fixing this?

My code:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

  var userNumber: String!

 @IBAction func callButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "telprompt://\(userNumber)")!)

}

@IBAction func textButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let message = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    message.body = ""
    message.recipients = ["\(userNumber)"]
    message.messageComposeDelegate = self


}

func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {


}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? You should be able to call MFMessageComposeViewController from (for example) didSelectRowAtIndexPath: in UIViewController - you don't need to do this in your (custom) UITableViewCell.

Comment: Updated. As you can see, I'm trying to have it where my custom cell has two buttons (call and text) and the numbers populate. I have this working for the call button but not for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed need a `UIViewController` to present a `MFMessageComposeViewController`. To solve your problem, you can add a property to your `TableViewCell`:

```
var viewController: UIViewController?
```

You need to assign the current view controller in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function - if the view controller is the data source of the table view, this would be just `cell.viewController = self`.

Then, in the `textButton` function, you can present the message composer:

```
self.viewController.presentViewController(message, true, nil)
```

For the dismissal in `didFinishWithResult`, just call

```
self.viewController.dismissViewController(true, nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I am not able to dismiss the message composer with didFinishWithResult as I'm not able to use dismissViewController. How would I fix this?

Comment: Also with `self.viewController` - see my updated answer.